# Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, 16.04, etc

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 3B068FB4789ABE4AEFA3BB491397BC53640DB551 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 3B068FB4789ABE4AEFA3BB491397BC53640DB551 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
```

How to fix this error? 
I have tried to delete .list3 like this

```
 sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3': No such file or directory
```

This what I get with `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` by opening a terminal and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

Then make sure you have no lines double in it. Or if you want to remove it use:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

Comment: @Videonautth Take a look at my edit,no lines double.

Comment: What happens if you remove the word `stable` and only leave `main` there in this line?

Comment: E: Malformed entry 3 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list (Suite)

Comment: Thats so weird, well, if you move this file out of this directory i guess youll be able to have a normal upgrade at least

Comment: What you as well can check is, if there is a google chrome line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`